# Combining the data in two columns into one for sorting

Tags: mysql, select, union

I am trying to UNION two columns in a SELECT, and alias to a third.

I also need to retrieve the data matching the WHERE clause, then sort by the aliased column (MLS_SORT).

**This, and variations of it that I have tried, don't work.**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT MLS_AGENT_ID AS MLS_SORT FROM mlsdata)

UNION

(SELECT MLS_OFFICE_ID AS MLS_SORT FROM mlsdata)

WHERE (MLS_AGENT_ID = $agent_narid) OR (MLS_OFFICE_ID = $office_narid)      

ORDER BY MLS_SORT
```

**This part does work and creates the MLS_SORT alias with the correct values, but I can't figure out how to limit the results to the WHERE clause above:**

```
(SELECT MLS_AGENT_ID AS MLS_SORT FROM mlsdata)

UNION

(SELECT MLS_OFFICE_ID AS MLS_SORT FROM mlsdata)
```

Am I at least going down the correct path or is this not the proper way to proceed?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to understand the syntax of UNION:  query UNION query

I think you want:

```
SELECT MLS_SORT
FROM
(
    SELECT MLS_AGENT_ID AS MLS_SORT 
      FROM mlsdata
     WHERE MLS_AGENT_ID = $agent_narid

    UNION

    SELECT MLS_OFFICE_ID AS MLS_SORT 
      FROM mlsdata
     WHERE MLS_OFFICE_ID = $office_narid
)
ORDER BY MLS_SORT
```

To get the two ID subsets into a single result set then sort them.

But, this whole query looks like it's going to give a two-row result set -- one row for an agent and another for an office.  Is that what you want?

Your logic effectively typecasts agent id and office id numbers into a single result set.  Does that make sense in your application?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I do wish to have one derived column, MLS_SORT, which will contain the combined results of the agent id and the office id. MLS_SORT doese not exist in the table.

Basically retrieve all records where agent id = agent id or office id = office id, combine agent id and office id data into one column, then sort by that column.

Comment: I tried your code but received:mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ....and mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource ...tried changing MLS_SORT to * with the same results.

Comment: I presume the $agent_narid and $office_narid items get substituted by whatever language you're using to write the code that issues the query (PHP?  you didn't mention it).   The messages you're getting are coming from that language,  not from the mySQL server.    You might try debugging with constants in place of those $variable items.  Once that works, you can get the substitution working.

Comment: Yes, PHP, sorry! I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
    select * from
    (
    (SELECT MLS_AGENT_ID AS MLS_SORT 
     FROM mlsdata
     WHERE (MLS_AGENT_ID = $agent_narid)
     )
    UNION
    (SELECT MLS_OFFICE_ID AS MLS_SORT 
     FROM mlsdata
     WHERE (MLS_OFFICE_ID = $office_narid)
     )) a
    ORDER BY MLS_SORT
```

**edit**:

alternate order by

```
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Hi Randy, using your example, (added ALL after union to get all 11 results), I got the correct result of the MLS_SORT column. Office and Agent Ids combined. However, even though the * was used, no other data is retrieved.

Comment: Even though the number of rows retrieved is 11, only the MLS_SORT column has data... If I change the * to any other column name (that exists), I get: 
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...any thoughts?

Comment: your order by must include one of the names in the subselect... you can try '1' instead to indicate order by the first column...